# Defining day between 18:00 and 18:00 next day

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to have a query identify each day from 18:00 the previous day, up until 18:00 the current day, this is a 24 hour period and then group transactions by that amount.

The general Idea is to make a query align with a banking End of Day report, which does not run on a natural day, rather this 18:00 to 18:00 day.

I am new to MySQL and am wondering if there is a use of interval or a date function that could simplify this query, or what the recommended approach would be.

Here is a snippet of the current query that groups on the entire date (midnight to midnight).  I am looking for a function that might replace DATE_FORMAT in the group by clause.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(totals.created_at,"%D %M %Y") as 'Date', warehouse.title ,sum(grand_total)
FROM totals
Join warehouse on warehouse.warehouse_id = totals.stock_id
WHERE
totals.created_at BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 21 DAY) AND NOW()
GROUP BY  totals.stock_id, DATE_FORMAT(totals.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d")
ORDER BY totals.created_at,warehouse.title
```

Comment: There is MySQL's [between](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) which should totally help you out

Comment: @NicoHaase Between is useful in the WHERE clause, can it also be used in the group by? I have not seen it used like that before.

Comment: Why do you want to use GROUP BY on multiple values in the WHERE clause? You edited the query to something that should work, and if not, you should specify what is not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using a simple test to then add a day to the date, using the following.

```
DATE_ADD(totals.created_at, INTERVAL CAST(time(totals.created_at) > time("18:00") AS SIGNED INTEGER) DAY )
```